# How can I find what uses the space in a LV(logical volume)?

Tags: centos, filesystems, mount, lvm

The logical volume(aka LV), `centos-home` is created automatically when installing CentOS 7 by default, but I didn't use it manually.

Now, I have mounted an **empty** directory, `work` to `centos-home`.

`/home/anselmo/work` ==> `/dev/mapper/centos-home`

The following are the results of `df -h` after mount.

```
[anselmo@anselmo-centos7 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem                                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos_anselmo--centos7-root   50G   45G  5.2G  90% /
devtmpfs                                   63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                      63G  302M   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                      63G   43M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                                      63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb3                                1014M  358M  657M  36% /boot
/dev/sdc1                                 200M   12M  189M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos_anselmo--centos7-home  2.6T  1.7T  948G  65% /home
tmpfs                                      13G   92K   13G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mapper/centos-home                    65G  8.8G   56G  14% /home/anselmo/work
```

Though I mounted an empty directory, the LV had already used space `8.8G`.

How can I find what uses this space?

Comment: What filesystem you use for this LV?

Comment: What is the output of the following commands: `ls -Rabl /home/anselmo/work` and `du -kx /home/anselmo/work` ?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm using LVM2 and xfs.

Comment: @telcoM It has another "anselmo" directory. It looks like my home directory at old time. Does it mean it is an used disk? I thought that I removed all partitions of the disk when I installed my OS, but the result seems that it is my misunderstanding.

Comment: When you installed CentOS 7, it auto-created that LV as you said. It also created a home directory for any regular user(s) specified during the installation, and populated the home directory (or directories) with the contents of /etc/skel. That plus the preallocation feature described by @RomeoNinov probably explain it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across this kind issue many times the actual issue here is the directory /home/anselmo/work has files/directories before it get mounted onto the LV /dev/mapper/centos-home.

Unmount this file system and check definitely the directory (/home/anselmo/work) has data in it, delete those and mount it back and you see it's 1 size utilised.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Q/A](https://serverfault.com/a/406070/293588) this is preallocated diskspace and it is related to "[XFS Dynamic Speculative EOF Preallocation](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=055388a3188f56676c21e92962fc366ac8b5cb72)"

> This is a move to reduce file fragmentation during streaming writes by
>   speculatively allocating space as file sizes increase. The amount of
>   space preallocated per file is dynamic and is primarily a function of
>   the free space available on the filesystem (to preclude running out of
>   space entirely).
>
> It follows this schedule:
>
> freespace       max prealloc size
>
> > 5%             full extent (8GB)
> >     4-5%             2GB (8GB >> 2)
> >     3-4%             1GB (8GB >> 3)
> >     2-3%           512MB (8GB >> 4)
> >     1-2%           256MB (8GB >> 5)
> >     <1%            128MB (8GB >> 6)
>
> This is an interesting addition to the filesystem as it may help with
>   some of the massively fragmented files I deal with.